# Echo out values of an array in a link

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have this array

```
[chest] => Array(
     [id] => 125835
     [name] => Warmongering Gladiator's Chain Armor
     [icon] => inv_chest_mail_raidhunter_p_01
     [quality] => 4
     [itemLevel] => 710
     [tooltipParams] => Array(
                           [set] => Array(
                                     [0] => 125835
                                     [1] => 125838
                                     [2] => 126038)

                           [transmogItem] => 71464
                           [timewalkerLevel] => 100
                                )
```

I echo out the [id], [icon], [quality], [set]

```
$items = $r['result']['items'];
echo 'chest: ID=' . $items['chest']['id'] . ', quality = ' . $items['chest']['quality'] . ', icon = ' . $items['chest']['icon'] . "\n";
foreach($items['legs']['tooltipParams']['set'] as $value){
    echo ''.$value.':';    
}
```

Now i need to echo out the informations in a html link. I tried it like this:

```
echo "<a href="//www.wowhead.com/item=. $items['chest']['id'] ." class=". $items['chest']['quality'] .pcs=. $value ."><img src="http://www.wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/large/. $items['chest']['icon'] ." alt="some_text"></a>"
```

Comment: Your quotes need attending. You can see from the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment points out, you need to escape double-quotes that you want to render as HTML. You also need to delimit array indices within your double-quoted string in curly braces, so that PHP knows that `$items['chest']['icon']` refers to a specific value, and doesn't try to parse `$items` by itself:

```
echo "<a href=\"//www.wowhead.com/item={$items['chest']['id']}\" class=\"{$items['chest']['quality']}\" pcs=\"$value\"><img src=\"http://www.wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/large/{$items['chest']['icon']}" alt=\"some_text\"></a>";
```

A couple additional things to note:

1. If the values inside `$items['chest']` are any kind of user input, be careful to escape them using `htmlspecialchars()` before rendering to prevent XSS
2. This is a good use-case for `sprintf()` IMHO, which eliminates the need for escaping double-quotes and delimiting array vars.